# How to return Eigen Matrix in a dll interface function

Tags: c++, eigen

Consider a class like the following with API indicating the exported function:

```
    class A
    {
        std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> C;
    public:
        Eigen::MatrixXd getMatrix(int i) { return C[i]; }
        //assume C always has enough elements to return
    }
    //Then a function from exe access the above as following
    void foo(){
        A a(); //assume something is generated in a.C
        {
            Eigen::MatrixXd c = a.getMatrix(10);
        }
        checkHeap(); //heap corruption detected
    }
```

How do I correctly return the matrix without getting errors from dll heap boundary issue.

EDIT: turns out the the derived class has a virtual overridden function that returns a non-temporary matrix. Edited the question to reflect that.
EDIT2: Found out that the build parameters between the test exe and dll were not consistent, leading to this error. It is now fixed.

Comment: Use the shared C runtime support library, that way you only have one heap.  If you are already using this then you have some other error in your program that is corrupting the heap.

Comment: Would you kindly point me to the runtime support library please? As far as I know, it is a header only library.

Comment: @PuiHoLam there are two ways you can link with the standard library in windows: 1) statically and 2) dynamically, this is what Richard meant: you have to use 2) when you're allocating from inside and sharing ownership of that memory across dll boundaries, when you link statically, the dll and the exe won't share the same allocator and thus get confused when trying to delete the other one's owned memory.

Comment: I know I can make my library a static one. But that would be my last solution. And no, he didn't mean it that way I am sure. C runtime support library is a dynamically linked one. By the way, changing the return type to reference type fixed this problem but breaks the parents' code since they share the same interface.